# Topological space whose fundamental group is the circular group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following problem: Find a space $X$ path-connected, whose universal covering is contractible and is such that $\pi_{1}(X)=\mathbb{S}^{1}$, where $\mathbb{S}^{1}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ and it is considered a group under multiplication.

A space $X$ that satisfies the above for a given group $G$ is usually called the space $K(G,1)$ (or Eilenberg-McLane space).

Now, since any element of $e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{S}^{1}$ can be represented by the matrix
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
 \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}

then we can consider $\mathbb{S}^{1}\cong U(1)\cong SO(2)$, where $U(1)$ is the special unit group and $SO(2)$ is the group of matrices $2\times 2$ such that its determinant is equal to $1$.

Furthermore I know that for any given group $G$, there is a $2$-dimensional cell complex  $X_{G}$ shuch that $\pi_{1}(X_{G})\cong G$, but how would you construct $X_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}$ in this case?

Furthermore, will the space $X_{\mathbb{S}^{1}}$ have a contractible space as a universal covering?

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have something in mind to give the $\pi_1(X)$ a topology?

Comment: Start with the $2$-dim cell complex with $\pi_1\cong S^1$.  Then you have to add $3$-dim cells to kill $\pi_2$, and add $4$-dim cells to kill $\pi_3$, etc.